# Attribute directive: Get an ElementRef width upon initialization

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-directive

I am unable to get the width of an ElementRef in an attribute directive, as it is always equal to `0`

The element where I define the attribute directive is:

```html
<ion-text myCustomDirective>Test Text</ion-text>
```

And the implementation of the directive goes like this:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myCustomDirective]'
})
export class MyCustomDirective implements OnInit {

  private element: any;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    console.log("Element width: " + this.element.offsetWidth) //The width here is always equal to 0
  }
}
```

I tried with different methods and attributes like `clientWidth`, `getComputedStyle(this.element)['width']`, but I always get `0`.

I think that the problem is that the element isn't yet rendered in the `onInit` hook, and I can't think of a way to get the width from another hook/method.

Since my element `ion-text` does not fire any events, I am not able neither to use a `HostListener` where I can get the width after my element initialization.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Even trying with the `ngAfterViewInit()` hook returns a width of `0`:

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  console.log("Element width: " + this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth); // returns 0
}
```

Comment: Can you try with a `setTimeout` call in ngOnInit to be sure that the value is changing ?

Comment: have you tried ngAfterViewInit(). it might solve your problem

Comment: can a setTimeout be accurate? How can we be sure that the value that is given to the timeout is sufficient so that the element is changing? This value may change regarding the performance of the machine and the browser that is executing the code

Comment: concerning ngAfterViewInit(), I just edited my question to mention that I am always getting a width of 0 even after using it

Comment: I have stackblitz and it's working fine here is link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arkuj2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Yes I see that it is working well. I took the same example and applied it in my code but I am always getting 0, I even changed the `ion-text` with a simple input as in the example but with no obvious change. I can't see yet what's causing this result in my code

Answer (score 1):

This issue might arise due to view is not initialize at the time of getting the width of the element. what you need here is use another lifecycle hook of the directive. [*ngAfterViewInit()*](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#ngAfterViewInit)

**Here is the solution**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myCustomDirective]'
})
export class MyCustomDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  private element: any;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    console.log("Element width: " + this.element.offsetWidth) //The width here is always equal to 0
  }
}
```

**[Here is solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arkuj2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I edited my question to point out that even the `ngAfterViewInit()` hook returns a width of 0